# Get class by regex/pattern from multiple

Tags: jquery

Is it possible in jquery to get a class from a pattern when an element has multiple classes.

For example

```
<body class="class-a class-b class-c id-1">
```

the class `id-1` is not known at runtime but i would like to get that class knowing only that there will be a class in a pattern of "id-" and then the id.

Basically i want the number 1 returned in the above example.

In this example i would want a number 6 returned:

```
<body class="class-a class-b class-c id-6">
```

Comment: Do yo have access to change the underlying code?  A data attribute would be much better.  Something like `data-id="6"`.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  Which is a shame as i agree that would be a better approach

Answer (score 0):

```
var klass = document.body.className.match(/\bid\-\d+/)[0];
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ahsKz/2/)

to get just the number at the end you can do:

```
var numb = klass.split('-').pop();
```

But if you're not even sure if there will be a number or a class at all, you should probably do some error handling as well :

```
klass = klass.length ? klass[0].indexOf('-') ? klass[0].split('-').pop() : null : null;
```

Comment: Probably want a `+` on the `\d` for multi-digit numbers.

Comment: @JamesMontagne - wasn't sure about that one, I initially added {2} for two digits, but removed it as the question only mentions one digit, but I'll add the +, as that way it would work either way.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with `.attr('class')` the returned classes of the tag

```
$('body').attr('class')
```

then you can apply your regex

```
 /\s+id\-(\d+)\s+/.exec($('body').attr('class'))
```

if a match is found, the required id number will be in the position 1 of the returned array

Comment: Your answer will match the class `void-1` as well. You need to check for a word boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? It would use an ID, rather than a class, which I think might be a bit "cleaner".

HTML:

```
<div class="class-a class-b class-c" id="item-6"></div>
```

JS:

```
var $item = $('.class-a.class-b.class-c');
var number = parseInt($item[0].id.substring(5), 10);
console.log(number);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S8vRr/

It gets all elements with that class pattern, then extracts the integer from the id of the first element of that set.

**Edit:** Just read your comment on the OP; seems like you can't set any IDs. This answer may have worked theoretically, but unfortunately not in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you'll have at most one `id-...` class applied to the `body` element you can use:

```
var classData = document.body.className.match(/\bid\-\d+\b/),
    numberData = classData && classData[0].substring(3);
```

`numberData` will be `null` if no such matches exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
var num;
var c = $("body").attr("class").split(" ");
$(c).each(function(index,value){
    if($(c)[index].match(/^id-/)){
       num = $(c)[index].replace(/^id-/,"");
       return false;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/itsmikem/h29p4/3/